# can't get 100% background color with drupal theme...tried several different ways

Tags: css, drupal-7

I have tried so many different methods to force my full page to have a black background and it still has white space on all sides of 8 pixels!

You will notice a LOT of code in my CSS, I only had the background code at the start.

Here is my CSS and my  tags layout:

```
<div id="full-width">
<div class="background">
    <div class="header-wrap">
        <div class="header">
        </div>
    <div class="nav-wrap">
      <div id="main-menu" class="nav">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="body-wrap">
        <div class="body">
            <div class="content">
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="subfooter-wrap">
        <div class="subfooter"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-wrap">
        <div class="footer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
#full-width {width: 100%; background: #000;}
html {-webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;background-size: cover;width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;background-color:black;}
.background {width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;background-color:black;}
.header-wrap {width:960px;}
.header {width:960px;margin:0 auto;height:120px;}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where is the _LOT_s of css? I don't see anything that could make the 8px white gap

Comment: I put your HTML and CSS in a jsfiddle and I don't see any white sides. Is there a url where we can see the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/245Fz/

Comment: Sure: http://groovymotion.com/ and the rest of my CSS code: #nav li a {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
.nav-wrap {border-left:1px solid #fff;border-right:1px solid #fff;}
.body-wrap {margin:0 auto;width:960px;}
.body {overflow: hidden;border:1px solid #cfcfcf;padding:10px;background:#fff;box-shadow:0 0 5px #808080;}
.content {width:720px;float:left;padding:0;}
.sidebar {width:200px;float:right;padding:0;}
.subfooter-wrap {margin:0 auto;}
.subfooter {margin:0 auto;width:960px;}
.footer-wrap {margin:0 auto;}
.footer {width:960px;border:1px solid #000000;margin:0 auto;}

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
body {
    background: #000;
}
```

You're setting background in `.background` but not on `body`. That `margin: 8px;` being referred to is in the `user agent stylesheet` (your browser default style). The white border is because the body background is white.

You can set margin to 0 in body if you want, but setting the background in the appropriate place might end up being cleaner as you probably want a small margin around the page anyway.

Also, since you're using Drupal you might want to keep in mind that you may need to clear the theme cache if you're aggregating/compressing CSS.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem comes because some where in your css files you or themes or modules have defined:

```
body {
      display: block;
      margin: 8px;
}
```

The easiest way would be to add:

```
body {
  margin: 0px !important;
}
```

where "!important" will overwrite other settings. The other way is to look for a file where you added "margin: 8px;"

Use google chrome browser or mozilla + right click -> inspect element good way for tracking class and so on.

Hope that help.

Comment: Thanks guys this worked and also clearing the cache. but for some reasons I need to clear the cache everytime I edit my css file

Comment: It's because in your drupal site settings: "admin/config/development/performance" you set:
BANDWIDTH OPTIMIZATION
v - Aggregate and compress CSS files. 
So it's mean drupal is creating cash file for css and if you will not clear cash drupal is using files from cash not the one you change.
It's good for performance not got when you are developing

Comment: Thanks szikael, I disabled all the caching while I am doing the dev

Comment: So if that answer help you may approve it, then other will know right way.